# "No such file or directory" при вызове file_get_contents

Tags: php

Собственно, код самый примитивный:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("example.xml");
?>
```

Выдает `No such file or directory`, хотя я совершенно уверен в том, что ошибки в названии файла нету и этот файл существует с правами 777. Более того, этой функцией я не могу открыть абсолютно никакой файл, в том числе с других сайтов (В этом случае `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`; Конечно, `allow_url_fopen = On`).

Comment: Ок. На файл 777, а на каталог?

Comment: Скрипт запускаете в корневой папке и получаете в ответ - No such file or directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022194/file-get-contents-no-such-file-or-directory-php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```